# If a bathroom exhaust fan does not have a duct on the side of it but I do have venting present in attic to the outside is my bathroom fan vented?

Tags: bathroom, fans

My current bathroom fan is ductless but a friend looked in my attic and said it is vented outside? Can a bathroom fan be venting outside if there is not a duct connected to the bathroom fan light?

Comment: Why did your "friend" say that and why do you claim there **isn't** ducting?   Take a look and see what's really going on.

Comment: I have never heard of a ductless bathroom fan. As petecon said it would be bad to have humid air dumping into the attic even if there are vents available.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're venting into the attic. Just because the attic is vented to the outside is irrelevant. So you're pumping water vapor into your attic, where it's being absorbed by your insulation. That's going to be nasty.

I recommend that you put some ducting in to vent the bathroom directly to the outside.

Comment: I don't think we've established what if any ductwork is actually connected to the fan.   I agree that it certainly should not dump into the attic, or into a wallspace.